# RBAC at project level in Openshift

Tags: openshift

Is there a way to create RBAC roles in such a way that only provides a user to create a project and be admin for that project?
I cannot create cluster-admin role restricted for a project as we dont know what project it can be.
The usecase is , a user should be able to create a project and be admin to only his project

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create an RBAC policy that will let them create a *specific* project. We handle this by having an onboarding system that permits people to request projects through a github pull request; when we approve the PR, our tooling creates the project and then sets up the requester as a project admin by creating per-project groups and rolebindings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `self-provisioner` role? I think this is what you are looking for.

That allows user to create projects. In that project they will then have local admin rights, except to modify quotas. Note that they actually have to use `new-project` to do this, they still can't just randomly create namespaces. (This is one of the reasons projects exist.)

Look at the [docs for RBAC](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/authentication/using-rbac.html), including self-provisioner and differences between admin and cluster-admin.

Also see [the section of project creation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/applications/projects/configuring-project-creation.html) including how you template out the new projects.